# How to make a call with Android pjsua2

Tags: android, pjsua2

I am a beginner with the pjsua2 technology, I managed to compile the pjsip technology and I use the example project "pjsua2 android". The application connects to my asterisk server, and can receive calls but can not make calls.

I have created a function that allows you to make a call, but it does not work.

**Here is the code**

```
Public static void CallPhone2(){
  String buddy_uri = "sip:301@192.168.43.106";

  MyCall call = new MyCall(account, -1);
  CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);

  try {
        call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm);              
      } catch (Exception e) {
         call.delete();
         return;
      }
      currentCall = call;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
String buddy_uri = "sip:301@192.168.43.106";
```

to something like this:

```
String buddy_uri = "sip:301@192.168.43.106:5060";
```

Assigning a port may help. Please post your logs also.

Answer (score 0):

check once ICE enabled ..

```
new AccountConfig().getNatConfig().setIceEnabled(true);
```

to try with TLS